# Problemas com API Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, api

Estou enfrentando um problema com uma API desenvolvida e consumida em laravel 8.

Estou fazendo a seguinte consulta no banco de dados:

```
**$propertiesexperience = Imovel::where([
                                    ['imovel.codempresa', $request->idempresa],
                                    ['imovel.negocio', $request->business],
                                    ['imovel.desativar', 0],
                                ])
                                ->leftJoin('imovel_images', function($imagem){
                                    $imagem->on('imovel.id', '=', 'imovel_images.codimovel')
                                    ->where('imovel_images.principal', 1); 
                                })
                                ->select('imovel.referencia', 'imovel.negocio', 'imovel.tipo', 'imovel.slug', 'imovel.valor', 'imovel.direitos', 'imovel.descricao', 'imovel.neighborhood', 'imovel.state', 'imovel.city', 'imovel.quarto', 'imovel.suites', 'imovel.garagem', 'imovel.banheiro', 'imovel.metragem', 'imovel.metragemutil', 'imovel_images.pasta', 'imovel_images.principal')
                                ->get()
                                ->toArray();**
```

Testando esse retorno atravéz do Postaman, tenho o retorno correto das informações.

Quando tento consumir em outra aplicação Laravel, sempre retorna NULL as informações.

Estou buscando essas informações da seguinte forma:

```
$propertyambience = Http::acceptJson()->post('http://localhost/myapp/public/api/experience', [
        'idempresa' => '9',
        'business'  => 'venda'
    ]);

    dd($propertyambience->json());
```

Desta forma a aplicação "Consumidora" da API nunca recebe as informações solicitadas. Estranho porque através do Postaman as informações são retornadas em formato JSON normalmente.

Alguém pode me dar uma dica do que possa estar acontecendo e como resolver isso?

Answer (score -2):

Acredito que o que pode estar faltando na requisição é o campo *Content-Type* no *headers* da requisição, assim:

```
{
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
```

Para usar objeto *$request* de dados que vem da rota de API do Laravel precisa desse campo no *headers* da requisição, se não é como se fosse que você não enviou nenhum dado na requisição. Se você utilizar rodas web não precisa disso.